# how to increase motor load capacity?

Tags: power-supply, motor

I have old cassete player 12v dc motor.while I supply 12v on it runs smoothly with speed of 300 rpm but when I put some load on it, its stop spining.once i tried 24v supply its runs for some time then after motor collaps,so I am afraid of loosing this one motor.even I used gear bt its slow down the speed.

Can I increase the load with-out decreasing the speed of the motor?

Comment: Why do you think it is possible?

Comment: Would be nice to understand what are you trying to do

Comment: Cassette player motors are deliberately designed for low torque, in order to limit tape breakage. If your application requires more torque, start with a different motor -- one that's designed for it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is the design of the machine itself. To have more torque at a fix speed, you need more current. This results in  a complete new design of the machine. You will need to fit bigger wire inside the machine stator, you will need more iron or different materials to create the proper leakage flux, etc...

In your case, you need to choose an electrical machine that is "stronger". A good starting point is to determine the nominal Torque and the nominal speed of your application. From that you can deduce the nominal Power require for your application with the equation

$$ P_{nom} =\tau_{nom} \omega_{nom} $$

The next step consist to determine the nominal voltage. With the nominal voltage and nominal power, you will have the choice of differents machines. This should be the first step of your design.

In your specific case, the nominal power of the motor you choose is clearly not enough. Sure the motor can spin at 300RPM with 12V, but you are actually consuming a very small amount of power if you don't have any loads. You just consume power to compensate the air friction. The gearbox also don't change anything. A gearbox only change the speed/torque ratio! If you decrease the speed by x2, you will need 2 time more torque! This is also the best case. In reality, a gearbox will increase the amount of power consume because its efficiency isn't 100%.

If you are able you can try to run again the motor you have with the 12V source with an amp-meter connected. When you reach 300RPM, you will see that the actual current draw is very low. If you put the load, you will see the spike in current. Because a motor spin doesn't mean that it consume power. The speed is related to Voltage and the torque is related to the current.

Comment: Any cassette players I had used some form of speed regulation in the motor itself. This enabled playback at the correct pitch over a range of voltages - particularly useful for battery powered equipment. There was usually a pot hidden behind a sticker.